# How can I change some of the names of variables within columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where i have a column (Continent) and i which to rename some of the data within this column, how would i do this. Data and example below;

I currently have these as the continents for countries in my dataset, i with to rename them so Australia would take Oceana instead of Western pacific, and Afghanistan would take Asia and not East Mediterranean.
Africa
Americas
East Mediterranean
Europe
South East Asia
Western Pacific

Part of my dataset here;
head(all_data,3)

```
     Country Year             Continent Life_Expectancy 
1 Afghanistan 2010 Eastern Mediterranean        61.17996                 
2 Afghanistan 2011 Eastern Mediterranean        61.72234       
3 Afghanistan 2012 Eastern Mediterranean        62.20652
```

tail(all_data,1)

```
      Country Year Continent Life_Expectancy 
4705 Zimbabwe 2010    Africa        52.91785
```

Comment: Are you looking for `ifelse()`? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: I think its a pretty simple fix, i just dont how the code/how to go about it. Just a case of changing all of 'Eastern Mediterranean' to Asia or Africa. Then all of south-East asia to Asia and Western Pacific to Oceana or Asia.  I guess ifelse could be used if you'd be kind enough to help me with an example on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `case_when` you could extend: (more conditions):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Continent = case_when(Country == "Afghanistan" ~ "Asia",
                               Country == "Australia" ~ "Oceana",
                               TRUE ~ Continent))


      Country Year Continent Life_Expectancy
1 Afghanistan 2010      Asia        61.17996
2 Afghanistan 2011      Asia        61.72234
3 Afghanistan 2012      Asia        62.20652
4   Australia 2012    Oceana        43.22200
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Australia"), Year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L), Continent = c("Eastern Mediterranean", 
"Eastern Mediterranean", "Eastern Mediterranean", "Western pacific"
), Life_Expectancy = c(61.17996, 61.72234, 62.20652, 43.222)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: best to add `TRUE~Continent` at the end of the `case_when`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although this is sort of what I'm after the only issue is that it returns an NA value for the countries that i don't wish to mutate.

Comment: Jave you tried the updated code

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[Country == 'Afghanistan', Continent := 'Asia'
   ][Country == 'Australia', Continent := 'Oceana'
     ]
```

With any `Country` not covered by our logic above, `Continent` would keep its original value. Also note latter statements take precedence.

## Benchmark

The advantage to this method is speed (scalability). In our benchmark with 20 million rows `data.table` performed > 4.5x more quickly:

```
# dummy data
x <- 1e7

df <- data.table(Country = rep(c('Afghanistan', 'Australia'), x)
                 , Continent = rep(c('x', 'y'), x)
                 )

# benchmark
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

xx <-
microbenchmark(dplyr_case = {df %>%
                                mutate(Continent = case_when(Country == "Afghanistan" ~ "Asia"
                                                             , Country == "Australia" ~ "Oceana"
                                                             , TRUE ~ Continent
                                                             )
                                        )
                              }
               , dt_subset = {df[Country == 'Afghanistan', Continent := 'Asia'
                                 ][Country == 'Australia', Continent := 'Oceana'
                                   ]
                              }
               , times = 10
               )

# plot
autoplot(xx)
```

[image: benchmark]