# How to use for loop and if conditions together in data.table?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, data.table

I have a `data.table` `dt` in R like this:

```
        ukey      time    orderType      a       edge        h1        h2
 1: 10600877   93003000       Buy       14.12      100      0.002      0.0002    
 2: 10600188   93003000       Buy       24.29      100      0.003      0.0003 
 3: 10600995   93003000       Buy       17.23      100      0.003      0.0003 
 4: 10600262   93003000      Sell       18.89      100      0.002      0.0004 
 5: 10600399   93003000      Sell       18.66      100      0.004      0.0002 
 6: 10603260   93003000      Sell       110.39     100      0.003      0.0002 
 7: 11000004   93003000      Sell       22.98      100      0.002      0.0003 
 ...
```

I want to get a new column called `check` by some conditions. My sample code looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
    if (dt[i, a - 1.5 * h1 > 111]) {
        dt[, check:= "A"]
        break
    }
    else if (dt[i, a+ edge - 1.3 * h1- 0.3 * h2> 111]) {
        dt[, check:= "B"]
        break
    }
    else if (dt[i, a- 1.5 * h1> 80]) {
        dt[, check:= "C"]
        break
    }
    else {dt[, check:= "D"]}
}
```

However, my code doesn't work well and it is inefficient. Could you give me some better solutions？Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `case_when` in `dplyr` package.

```
dt[, check := case_when((a - 1.5 * h1) > 111 ~ "A",
                        (a+ edge - 1.3 * h1- 0.3 * h2)> 111 ~ "B",
                        (a- 1.5 * h1) > 80 ~ "C",
                        TRUE ~ "D")]
```

Result looks like :

```
> dt
       ukey     time orderType      a edge    h1    h2 check
1: 10600877 93003000       Buy  14.12  100 0.002 2e-04     B
2: 10600188 93003000       Buy  24.29  100 0.003 3e-04     B
3: 10600995 93003000       Buy  17.23  100 0.003 3e-04     B
4: 10600262 93003000      Sell  18.89  100 0.002 4e-04     B
5: 10600399 93003000      Sell  18.66  100 0.004 2e-04     B
6: 10603260 93003000      Sell 110.39  100 0.003 2e-04     B
7: 11000004 93003000      Sell  22.98  100 0.002 3e-04     B
```

Hope it is useful.

Comment: Thanks. But I have a question. I want a situation that if the first case is True, then ingore the rest conditions. If not, then go to the second conditions. There are priorities among conditions otherwise some conditions might conflict. Is this true in your code sample?

Comment: `case_when` follows the order that you input your condition in the function. When it meets a condition that fit, ignore the rest.

Comment: yes it works well. appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a faster `ifelse` equivalent

## subset method

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

# initialise
dt[, check := "D"]

# faster ifelse
dt[a- 1.5 * h1> 80, check := "C"
   ][a+ edge - 1.3 * h1- 0.3 * h2> 111, check := "B"
     ][a - 1.5 * h1 > 111, check := "A"
       ]
```

Notice the latter subset conditions take precedence. Thus, orders are reversed i.e. C, B, A. Anything not captured by our conditions are left with initialised value i.e. D

[Similar post & performance gain vs dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213938/how-can-i-change-some-of-the-names-of-variables-within-columns/71214070#71214070)

## data.table's fcase

```
# courtesy to SO user @langtang
df[, check := fcase(a - 1.5 * h1 > 111, 'A'
                    , a + edge - 1.3 * h1 - 0.3 * h2 > 111, 'B'
                    , a - 1.5 * h1 > 80, 'C'
                    , default = 'D'
                    )]
```

notice with this method earlier conditions take precedence. Thus, order is A, B, C.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. I want a situation that if the first case is True, then ingore the rest conditions. If not, then go to the second conditions. There are priorities among conditions otherwise some conditions might conflict. Is this true in your code sample?

Comment: Hi. This is already coded in. Hence, the intentional reverse order e.g. if a row satisfies both condition C and A, that row will be assigned A

Comment: @SweepyDodo here and in your previous post, why don't you comment on or refer to the use of `data.table::fcase()`.. Just curious.

Comment: @langtang there is a very good reason....... I simply was not aware of its existence XD. Thank you for brining this up. Answer edited.